# CapacitorSQLitePlugin: Protocol message contained an invalid tag (zero)

Tags: sqlite, capacitor, ionic6

Im using the Capacitor community sqlite plugin and it was working all along. I added a few more pages to my Ionic app and build the app again and this error started. Im getting this error in the Android Studio IDE when i run the app

I was expecting the app would run as usual

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CapacitorSQLPlugin: Protocol message contained in invalid tag (zero)

I have the same problem. But it doesn't happen to me on all devices. In virtual machines it seems to work fine (Pixel 3). On an OPPO Android 12 physical phone, the error occurs. On a CAT phone with android 11 it worked fine too.

In case it may be of interest to you, I have sent an incident to capacitor-community.

https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite/issues

Comment: That is very true this issue seems to be happening on some devices and working on some devices.

Comment: Wait , the issue was not solved ??